# Connect to Sql Server on Win 10 from macbook

Tags: sql-server, macos, windows-10

I have SQL Server running on my Windows 10 laptop and I would like to connect to my databases on this server from my macbook.

I have enabled the network access for the SQL Server and have added a SQL login.

After this what other steps should I be taking to connect to the DB?

Comment: What tool do you want to connect with from your mac? Azure Data Studio / SQL Operations Studio work on mac

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your macbook is connect to the server pc with valid ip address,create one user in server with privileges(it depend on your how much access you have to give other user), after that use connection string with created user id and password,mention correct ip addreess in connection string.

String connection = "server= 'ip address of server pc';user id='user_name';database='database_name';password='password'";